# Filter results to display only those with duplicate records from one column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to filter my query in such a way that the results show only accounts with duplicate values. As it stands, my code is giving me both singular and duplicate accounts.

Here's my current query:

```
SELECT 
  l.AcctNum,
  l.SymID,
  l.PaymentHistory_1,
  h.postdatetime,
  h.NewCHAR
FROM Loans AS L WITH (nolock)
LEFT JOIN History AS H WITH (nolock) ON l.acctnum = h.acctnum
WHERE l.paymenthistory_1 = '12' 
  AND l.SymID LIKE '0%'  
  AND h.NewCHAR LIKE 'Rate decreased from%' 
ORDER BY l.acctnum
```

Currently I'll see results like this:

```
AcctNum    Sym ID    PaymentHistory    PostDate       New CHAR
123          1           blah           1/1/2000       Rate decreased from
125          1           blah           1/1/2000       Rate decreased from
160          1           blah           1/1/2000       Rate decreased from
160          1           blah           1/1/2000       Rate decreased from
```

What I'd like to see is this:

```
AcctNum    Sym ID    PaymentHistory    PostDate       New CHAR
160          1           blah           1/1/2000       Rate decreased from 2 to 1
160          1           blah           1/1/2000       Rate decreased from 3 to 2
```

Comment: I would highly recommend not using `with (nolock)` - its really not good practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try it:

```
SELECT AcctNum
     , SymID
     , PaymentHistory_1
     , postdatetime
     , NewCHAR
  FROM (
        SELECT l.AcctNum
             , l.SymID
             , l.PaymentHistory_1
             , h.postdatetime
             , h.NewCHAR
             , COUNT(1) OVER(PARTITION BY l.AcctNum) AS CountAcctNum
          FROM Loans AS L WITH(nolock)
          LEFT JOIN History AS H WITH(nolock) ON l.acctnum = h.acctnum
         WHERE l.paymenthistory_1 = '12'
           AND l.SymID LIKE '0%'
           AND h.NewCHAR LIKE 'Rate decreased from%'
       ) LoansHistory
 WHERE CountAcctNum > 1
 ORDER BY AcctNum
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I gave it a go, but I get an error that there is incorrect syntax near the keyword WHERE. I don't see anything that could be causing the issue however. Any thoughts?

Comment: I forgot the alias for subquery. Please, try again.